# Formatting React selection dropdown options

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-select

Is there a way to format the options of a React input dropdown?

For example I would like to have an autocomplete dropdown that displays the options in a formatted fashion with columns. Almost like a dropdown data grid so that the user can see "Name", "Address", etc. in a uniform way.

Answer (score -1):

React will render whatever you want into the DOM with the classes or styles that you choose. Solving the design problem wouldn't be any different then if you were just doing it with just html and css.

The React part of the equation is going to be handling interactions and making sure the right classes/styles end up on the right components. You can also always just opt into using a third party library built in react like http://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/

Comment: I am currently using react-select. However I do not know how to format the rows into allowing a set amount of space for Name, Date, etc.

Comment: with react-select you can pass in two props: `optionClassName` and `className`. you can pass any string to `optionClassName` and it will add that as a class to each options row and `className` does the same thing except it adds the class to the container. So to have control you could do something like `className='my-custom-select' and 'optionClassName=my-custom-select-option`. then just use css to adjust padding and margins

Comment: @finalfreq That's not what he is trying to achieve.

Comment: @GenoDiaz In this case, you need to create your own component.

Comment: I am quickly realizing this. I may just fall back on react-griddle as it is almost what I am looking for with the exception of not being a dropdown